# How to use several src and dest with grunt cssmin task?

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to use grunt cssmin on two files: style.css and ie.css (without concatenating them).

For the moment I have this in my grunt.js:

```
cssmin: {
  dist: {
    src: ['<banner:meta.wpblock>', '../style.css'],
    dest: '../style.css'
  }
},
```

Is it possible to specify several src (../style.css and ../ie.css) and several dest (../style.css and ../ie.css)?

Comment: Where did you get the cssmin task? It's not in grunt out of the box?

Comment: It's a plugin. You can get it here: https://github.com/jzaefferer/grunt-css

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently no, although when grunt 0.4 is released and the task is updated accordingly, you'll be able to do:

```
cssmin: {
  dist: {
    files: {
        '../style.css': ['<banner:meta.wpblock>', '../style.css'],
        '../style.css': ['<banner:meta.wpblock>', '../style.css']
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Thanks Sindre, I'm waiting for the 0.4 then :)

Answer (score 5):

I think you could use grunt's [compact format](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/docs/api.md#thisfile--grunttaskcurrentfile) to do this.

For example:

```
cssmin: {
    'production/css/style.css': ['<banner:meta.wpblock>', 'css/style.css'],
    'production/css/ie.css': ['<banner:meta.wpblock>', 'css/ie.css']
},
```